# Treating Special and Escape characters while loading data into SQL Table

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, special-characters

I am calling a REST API and loading the data into Blob container CSV file. One column has some values in Japanese and another column has values with escape characters. I have been suggested below approaches

1. Set the column value to NULL or BLANK wherever we get the Japanese characters - How to do this?
2. Remove the entire record which has Japanese value for any column - How to do this also?
3. How to treat the columns which has escape characters before storing the data into CSV?

Kindly suggest some ideas on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can update these columns in the Azure sql database using the below queries.

I tried it with the below sample data.

[image]

1. **Update column to blank** where value contains Special characters.

   ```
   update table1
   set LastName = ''
   where convert(varchar(100),LastName) like '%?%'
   ```

**Result**:

[image]

2. **Update column to NULL** where value contains Special characters.

   ```
    update table1
    set LastName = NULL
    where convert(varchar(100),LastName) like '%?%'
   ```

**Result**:

[image]

3. **Delete the entire row** where the value contains special characters.

   ```
    delete from table1
    where convert(varchar(100),LastName) like '%?%'
   ```

**Result**:

[image]

4. **Remove escape characters** from a column value.

   ```
   update table1
   SET MiddleName = replace(replace(MiddleName, '/',''),'\','')
   where MiddleName like '%\%' or MiddleName like '%/%'
   ```

**Result**:

[image]